# possible to lookup address locations with graphhopper via url?

Tags: graphhopper

I can't find any information so is it possible to lookup a address localtion (lat, long) with graphhopper via url like the search.php in nominatim?
thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

GraphHopper is a purely routing engine and there is no plan yet to add address search. Still we offer address search in our Directions API for business.